# Finding path around object on 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, concept

I have a vector of points that form a shape on a 2D grid. The shape is often a rectangle, but it sometimes forms "L" shapes. I am trying to find a path that is 1 tile outside the object, all the way around. So if the original shape is a 2x2 square then my path would be a 4x4 square tracing around the smaller square. I have found a method for finding a convex hull of a finite set of points: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan , but I am not sure how to get the path that is one tile outside these boundaries. I have thought about using A* to find a path from one side of the object to the other side, and then repeating the process for the rest of the way around, but finding the exact opposite side of the object is difficult when the object is not a perfect square. Any advice on strategy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just do wall following? Eg pick the leftmost point of your shape, and start one point to the left of it, facing up. Keep track of your current direction. At every step, if you can move a point to the right, do that (and you'll now be facing right). Otherwise move up, and if you can't do that move left, then down if that fails. Those directions are always relative to your current direction. Keep going until you reach your starting point again.

Comment: That is a good idea, however I am not sure how to do that without relative directions. There is no "direction that I am facing", just a set of points on a grid. Do you think that I should program a sort of AI that keeps track of the direction it is currently facing?

Comment: `Convex Hull` is not what you are looking for since you need the path just around the object and it would fail for an `L` shape. If all the points in your grid are one next to the other @canton7 algorithm will work. There is no need for an "AI", just a few `if` statements (the difference in your location is where you are facing)...

Comment: Okay, I do run into an issue that I am not allowed to backtrack on my path and sometimes there is a one tile hole in the object sort of like a U shape. If I go into that one tile then I can't get back out. I guess that if I run into that situation I should pop the last move of the path and mark that tile as invalid, then continue like I was doing before?

Comment: Well yes, I did say you need to keep track of which way you're currently facing. You can do that with a variable, or comparing your previous and current points. Not sure if call that an AI, but imagine a little robot following the wall around if that makes it easier

Comment: Actually here's a better idea, which won't work for hollow shapes. Start with your original set of points. For every point, take the points in all directions (including diagonals) and add them to a new set. Take all the points which appear in the second set but not the first. To exclude your dead-end paths, remove all points which only have another point on a single side.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Canton7, unfortunately my shapes are hollow. Can you think of a way that I could fill in the shape and then apply that? Maybe a flood fill? The problem is that I would have to determine which is the inside, and which is the outside of the shape